# Query currency rates with shorter syntax in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm aware of the GOOGLEFINANCE function provided by default in Google Sheets:

```
INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPUSD", "close", A2), 2, 2)
```

However, as you can clearly see, it takes ages to write. Plus, it makes functions less comprehensible. Is there a middleware that has a lighter syntax? Maybe something that doesn't need the INDEX function?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: _as you can clearly see, it takes ages to write_ I rather think that this is a matter of opinion &/or design style &/or spreadsheet layout. Have you looked at the examples in the documentation for [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) where the various attributes (ticker,attribute,date, etc) are written as cell values, and the function is written so as to reference the cells. Of course, `INDEX` is **not** a compulsory part of a `GOOGLEFINANCE` formula.  As to your question, I should be interested in your research as requested by @Rubén.